# Ruby filelist exclude a folder

Tags: ruby, rake, filelist

Here are all things I have tried:

```
  files = FileList.new("c:/temp/**/*") do |file|
    file.exclude("c:/temp/logs/")
  end


files = FileList.new("c:/temp/**/*") do |file|
  file.exclude("c:/temp/logs")
end

  files = FileList.new("c:/temp/**/*") do |file|
    file.exclude("c:/temp/logs/*.*")
  end


  files = FileList.new("c:/temp/**/*") do |file|
    file.exclude("c:/temp/logs/**/*")
  end


  files = FileList.new("c:/temp/**/*") do |file|
    file.exclude("c:/temp/**/logs/")
  end
```

rake version is  0.9.2.2 and Ruby version is 193.
all doesn't work. How  should I exclude a directory in a filelist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you're trying to get a listing of all files under `c:/tmp` except for anything in (and including) the `c:/tmp/logs` folder:

```
files = FileList.new("c:/temp/**/*").exclude(/c:\/temp\/logs/)
```

**[Edit]** See the documentation for [`FileList#exclude`](http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/Rake/FileList.html#M000152) for more details.  For example, to exclude multiple directories you can either add multiple string/regex arguments, modify the regular expression to match all directory patterns to be excluded, or do something similar in a block.

```ruby
x1 = /c:\/temp\/logs/ # The entire "c:/temp/logs" folder.
x2 = /\.zip$/i # Any file whose name ends with ".zip".
FileList.new("c:/temp/**/*").exclude(x1, x2)
```

Comment: It works cool, what about excluding multiple folders or files?

Comment: You should be able to chain excludes